# Adding a comment to last column of query but not updating it in database

Tags: mysql, sql

*** SOLUTION IN BOTTOM****
I am trying to add some comment at last column of my query , basically if  technical_document.disc_id contains "KN" then i want to add a comment to the last column of query 'OK'

but i cant get it working

```
    SELECT 

technical_document.project_no,
technical_document.doc_no,
technical_document.doc_class,
technical_document.disc_id,
tag_document.project_id AS "COMMENT"

CASE WHEN technical_document.disc_id = 'KN' THEN tag_document.project_id = "YES"

FROM technical_document left join tag_document on technical_document.doc_no = tag_document.proj_doc_doc_no



WHERE tag_document.proj_doc_doc_no IS NULL
AND technical_document.project_no like '%%'
AND technical_document.doc_class = ANY ('A','S','SE')
AND technical_document.Lci_Code = ANY ('A','A1','B')
```

---

Thanks for your help, here is how it was solved, sorry for confusing/misleading explanation on my part:

```
SELECT 

technical_document.project_no,
technical_document.doc_no,
technical_document.doc_class,
technical_document.disc_id, 

CASE 
            WHEN technical_document.disc_id LIKE 'KN' THEN 'OK'
            WHEN technical_document.disc_id LIKE 'K6' THEN 'OK'
            ELSE null 
        END



FROM technical_document left join tag_document on technical_document.doc_no = tag_document.proj_doc_doc_no


WHERE tag_document.proj_doc_doc_no IS NULL
AND technical_document.project_no like '%%'
AND technical_document.doc_class = ANY ('A','S','SE')
AND technical_document.Lci_Code = ANY ('A','A1','B')
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?  Sample data and desired results would probably help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Why do you use one column, aliased as `COMMENT`, and then override some value using that `CASE` statement? What should that do?

Comment: i want the tag_document.project_id AS "COMMENT" to contain "OK" whenever it finds the "KN" in technical_document.disc_id  column... sorry for my bad explanation.... maybe there is a better way to add a new column rather the using AS on a empty column as i have done

Answer (score 0):

I would write the query as:

```
SELECT d.project_no, d.doc_no, d.doc_class, d.disc_id,
       d.project_id AS COMMENT,
       (CASE WHEN td.disc_id = 'KN' THEN td.project_id = 'YES' END)
FROM technical_document d LEFT JOIN
     tag_document td
     ON d.doc_no = td.proj_doc_doc_no
WHERE d.proj_doc_doc_no IS NULL AND
      d.project_no like '%%' AND  -- not needed
      d.doc_class IN ('A', 'S', 'SE') AND
      d.Lci_Code IN ('A', 'A1', 'B');
```

First, you have a `WHERE` clause that says that there is no match.  Hence, including columns in the `SELECT` from `tag_document` doesn't make sense.  I suspect you intend:

```
SELECT d.project_no, d.doc_no, d.doc_class, d.disc_id,
       d.project_id as COMMENT,
       (CASE WHEN td.disc_id = 'KN' THEN td.project_id = 'YES' END)
FROM technical_document d LEFT JOIN
     tag_document td
     ON d.doc_no = td.proj_doc_doc_no AND td.disc_id = 'KN'
WHERE d.project_no like '%%' AND  -- not needed
      d.doc_class IN ('A', 'S', 'SE') AND
      d.Lci_Code IN ('A', 'A1', 'B');
```

Note the condition on `td` in the `WHERE` clause has been removed.

In addition:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- `= ANY` is allowed, but the colloquial operator is `IN`.
- Various small syntax errors are fixed -- missing commas, missing `END`.

Comment: This gave me a error on case statement saying missing keyword right after 'YES', i also added "" to COMMENT... was that correct?

Comment: @TrulsSønsteby . . . The syntax for the `case` expression is correct.  `comment` is not a reserved word in MySQL, so the double quotes are not necessary.